# Can't initialize linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I'm trying to build a stack using a linked list but I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error in my `linkedListStackInit` method;

**LinkedList.h**

```
#ifndef LinkedListStack_h
#define LinkedListStack_h

#ifndef __TYPE
#define __TYPE
#define TYPE int
#define TYPE_SIZE sizeof(int)
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

struct Link;
struct LinkedListStack;
void linkedListStackInit(struct LinkedListStack *s);
void push(struct LinkedListStack *s, TYPE data);
void pop(struct LinkedListStack *s);
TYPE top(struct LinkedListStack *s);
int isEmpty(struct LinkedListStack *s);

#endif
```

**LinkedList.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "LinkedListStack.h"

struct Link {
    TYPE value;
    struct Link *next;
};

struct LinkedListStack {
    struct Link *firstLink;
};

void linkedListStackInit(struct LinkedListStack *s) {
    s->firstLink = 0;
}

void push(struct LinkedListStack *s, TYPE data) {
    struct Link *newLink = malloc(sizeof(struct Link));
    // Assert?
    newLink->next = s->firstLink;
    newLink->value = data;
    s->firstLink = newLink;
}

void pop(struct LinkedListStack *s) {
    struct Link *temp = s->firstLink;
    s->firstLink = s->firstLink->next;
    free(temp);
}

TYPE top(struct LinkedListStack *s) {
    return s->firstLink->value;
}

int isEmpty(struct LinkedListStack *s) {
    if(s == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "LinkedListStack.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    struct LinkedListStack *s;
    linkedListStackInit(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is the TYPE field that you're copying in to the value field of the Link struct larger than an int?

Comment: What line does your debugger tell you the error occurs on? And then what are the values of any relevant pointers on that line? If for some reason the debugger can't help you find the problem then please post a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, so I realized the error actually occurs as soon as I try to initialize the linked list.  I posted all of the code so this should be more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your main method you are calling the function linkedListStackInit and passing stack (s) to it. But you haven't allocated memory to s before passing it to the linkedListStackInit function. The function linkedListStackInit doesn't allocate the memory either and tries to assign a value to its "firstlink" member. Try to do the following in your linkedListStackInit function and see if you can proceed further.

`s = malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedListStack));`

Comment: I get the same `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` problem in my `push` function.  Am I properly allocating memory there, or is there an issue in that as well?

Comment: Also in your main function, you seem to be not doing anything except initializing your stack by calling the linkedListStackInit method. You are not calling the push or pop.

Comment: Right, I'm saying if I use `push` I still get the same error, although I think I've allocated the memory for a new link properly in `push()`.

Comment: Same problem even if you call push directly without calling the init method. You are not allocating memory to stack ANYWHERE.

Comment: You solved my init problem, I'm just wondering if the same problem is present in my `push` method because I'm getting the same error in `push` AFTER i've successfully initialized the list.

Comment: Sorry, I was pulled into something important. A pointer in C is passed by value and not by reference. If you want to change the pointer inside the function you need to pass the actual pointer as a pointer, i.e. a pointer to a pointer. Try changing the Push method signature to "void push(struct LinkedListStack **stack, TYPE data)". And from main, pass the address of stack pointer instead of stack pointer itself.

Comment: How would I set `firstLink` to 0?  `s->firstLink` won't work.

Comment: I get the error: `member reference base type 'struct LinkedListStack *' is not a structure or union`

Comment: I just got home from work. Like I said earlier, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer to your stack variable to the init method. I tried to run your program with this correction. Check it out: "http://__goo.gl/lp002f". (Remove the 2 underscore characters from the short link).